# Multiple link between 2 tables columns...bad design approach?

Tags: java, database, database-design

[image: Example]

Hello
I'm developing a webapp and i'm about to design the database, i came across this question.
Is it a bad design to have more then 1 link between 2 tables?
The picture i have posted is a very quick and small example just to make it clearer.
If i would like to display all the offers,i would like to insert also the products they are related to, in this case i could retrieve the product name by creating a product instance retrieved with the product id from the product id field in the offer object, but it would require more queries execution and more typing work, so i was thinking to include the product name directly in the offer so that i can simply  retrieve all offers and eventually display the related product by browsing the DB with its product id.
Would you consider this a bad approach?
I have been looking around for cases like mine but i have only found approaches with 1 connection between tables (with unique id's)
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is data denormalization.  Don't do it (in most cases).  Design the tables correctly, let the database do the correct work with the correct queries.  It will be much easier to maintain and work with over time.

Use the ID in the offer table to lookup the product name in the products table.

Comment: Hi Joe thank you, would you create a field "product name" in the offer class that will be feeded with a setter only in case will be request for display? or would you create a third class which includes information from both objects?

Comment: @JBoy - You need to stop thinking about your database entities as classes.  The rules for normalization will lead you to reduce redundancy between entities (tables).  However, your classes in code can have as much redundancy as you want, with the data layer providing the contents for each member from the appropriate tables or joins of tables as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

yes this would be bad.

removing the redundant name would be proper normalization.  just link on the id, that will be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

In general there is no limit to the number of relationships (links) between two tables, but each relationship should have a unique meaning.  If, in your example, Product Name and Product ID are both candidate keys and each name always has the same ID then you should *definitely not* have two PK/FK relationships between these tables.

Answer (score 0):

@Joe is right.  Normalization is the best approach to take with database design.  The reason being so that additions, deletions, and modifications of a field can be made in just one table and then propagated through the rest of the database via the defined relationships.